# Greeting Message Not Change PHP

Tags: php

I'm Write code for greeting message using php. and its correct. but not changing messages. only one message shown "Good morning". there is another way to write code for greeting message or. can i changes in my code and how to do? please help.

```
<?php 
function greeting_msg()
{
    $hour = date('h');

    if ($hour >= 20) {
        echo "Good Night!";
    } elseif ($hour > 17) {
        echo "Good Evening!";
    } elseif ($hour > 11) {
        echo "Good Afternoon!";
    } elseif ($hour < 12) {
        echo "Good Morning!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Not changing messages __when__?

Comment: `H` is for 24-hour format. `h` is for 12-hour format (AM/PM). So `date('h')` will *always* give you a value no greater than 12. You need `date('H');`

Comment: As long as `date()` returns strings as a result of the given format, you have a problem with leading zeros using the format `h` or `H`. Instead of them use `G` as a 24 hours based format without leading zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to the documentation of the PHP [date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), your code is not correct.

```
date('H'); // 24 hours with leading zeros
date('h'); // 12 hours with leading zeros
date('G'); // 24 without leading zeros
```

So your code is ending up with values up to twelve and it 's correct, that the 'Good Morning!' message is displayed.

Next you have to check the value of your `$hour` variable. Just dump the value with code looking something like this ...

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($hour);
echo "</pre>";
```

As long as the PHP `date()` function is returning strings as a result of the given format, you can run into several problems.

```
date('h'); // could be '03' ('03' != 3)
date('H'); // could also be '03' ('03' != 3)
date('G'); // results into '3' (3 == 3)
```

Then look at your if/else conditions. Does the expected value fit in your conditions? Guess the value is `20`.

The value `20` would fit your first three conditions. The first condition is executed and so you 'll get the expected result 'Good night!'.

Just test your code this way.

Comment: yeah! but i changed and try H and h. not working. what lines i need to change my code?

Comment: Can you echo the `$hour` variable? Also, how do you check if the message is correct? Do you change your computer time or server time, or is this application only local?

Comment: @TharukaDananjaya Keep in mind, it depends on the time on the server. If the server-time is somewhere between midnight and mid-day, it will still show that. `date('H')` will work, though.

Comment: Marcel thank you for responding. change my computer time and reload page. but always good morning.

Comment: What is the value of `$hour`? As Koen said before, it 's important to know the value in such a case. Is the value the expected value?

Comment: @Marcel this is the result. Good Morning!

string(2) "11"

Comment: As long as 11 is smaller than 12 the message 'God Morning!' is right. Seems to work fine.

Comment: @ Marcel how can i change the time

Comment: Just do something like `$hour = 22` for testing reasons.

Comment: Have you tried using `date('G')` instead of `date('H')`. I guess you 'r running into a problem with leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change `H` instead of `h` to get 24 hour i.e

```
date('H'); // 24 hours
date('h'); // 12 hours
```

then you need to add few more condtions to get correct messages

```
$hour = date('H');
if ($hour > 5 && $hour < 10) {
    echo 'Good Morning';
} elseif ($hour > 11 && $hour < 17) {
    echo 'Good Afternoon';
} elseif ($hour > 17 && $hour < 20) {
    echo 'Good Evening';
} else {
    echo 'Good Night';
}
die;
```

Comment: If a condition fails, it will try the next condition. So you do not need to make it this complex, just try from the top down, i.e. `if ($hour > 20 || $hour < 5) { Night } elseif ($hour > 17) { Evening } elseif {$hour > 12) { afternoon } else {morning }`.

Comment: M.Hemant thanks for responding. now time is 2.24 pm but message shown good night. still that problem

Comment: tell me your current timezone, mine was date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); // india time And its showing `Good Afternoon` now

Comment: the computer time zone is (UTC+05:30) SriJayawardenepura

Comment: @Qirel can you tell me when it will fail?

Answer (score 0):

I've made small testing of your code and here is what we have

```
function greeting_msg($hour)
{
    $hour = $hour ?: date('H');
    if ($hour >= 20) {
        return "Good Night!";
    } elseif ($hour > 17) {
        return "Good Evening!";
    } elseif ($hour > 11) {
        return "Good Afternoon!";
    } elseif ($hour < 12) {
        return "Good Morning!";
    }
}

$hoursRange = range(1, 24); // contain range between 1 to 24
foreach ($hoursRange as $range) {
    echo sprintf('For %d message is: %s <br>', $range, greeting_msg($range));
}
```

Output in your case is

```
For 1 message is: Good Morning! 
For 2 message is: Good Morning! 
For 3 message is: Good Morning! 
For 4 message is: Good Morning! 
For 5 message is: Good Morning! 
For 6 message is: Good Morning! 
For 7 message is: Good Morning! 
For 8 message is: Good Morning! 
For 9 message is: Good Morning! 
For 10 message is: Good Morning! 
For 11 message is: Good Morning! 
For 12 message is: Good Afternoon! 
For 13 message is: Good Afternoon! 
For 14 message is: Good Afternoon! 
For 15 message is: Good Afternoon! 
For 16 message is: Good Afternoon! 
For 17 message is: Good Afternoon! 
For 18 message is: Good Evening! 
For 19 message is: Good Evening! 
For 20 message is: Good Night! 
For 21 message is: Good Night! 
For 22 message is: Good Night! 
For 23 message is: Good Night! 
For 24 message is: Good Night!
```

Which mean that your system is saying "Good morning" starting from 01:00, which isn't true. I've made some minor changed to your conditions:

```
function greeting_msg()
{
    $hour = date('H');
    if ($hour >= 20 || $hour < 5) {
        return "Good Night!";
    } elseif ($hour > 17) {
        return "Good Evening!";
    } elseif ($hour > 11) {
        return "Good Afternoon!";
    } else {
        return "Good Morning!";
    }
}
```

I don't know is 05:00 is Morning for somebody, but I've set it :) And now range from 20:00 to 05:00 is showing "Good Night".

Also, don't forget that server time can have different timezone from yours.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `date('h')` and `date('H')` is that one is using the 24-hour format (`H`) and one is using the 12-hour format (`h`). So, when you do `date('h')`, you will *always* get values from 0-12.

From the date manual,

```
| Format | Description                                      | Values        |
|--------|--------------------------------------------------|---------------|
| h      |  12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    | 01 through 12 |
| H      |  24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    | 00 through 23 |
```

This means that the behavior you are describing is correct, as `date('h')` will be no more than 12, and you are checking for `date('h') < 12`, a condition that will always be true.

Using `date('H')`, and some minor adjustments is shown below (we echo the result of the function, not inside it, and some logical changes to simplify readability).

```
function greeting_msg() {
    $hour = date('H');

    if ($hour > 20 || $hour < 5) { 
        return "Good night"; 
    } elseif ($hour > 17) {
        return "Good evening";
    } elseif ($hour > 12) {
        return "Good afternoon";
    } else {
        return "Good morning";
    }
}
echo greeting_msg();
```

- Test of all hours where we mimic the 24 hours at https://3v4l.org/B8qC0
- [PHP.net on `date()`](http://php.net/date)

Comment: @ Qirel this is right. i tried to change my pc time and check it. now change the message but only morning and evening.

Comment: The logic is as follows, if `$hours` is between 21-24 and 0-5, then its evening. If it's between 18-20, it's evening. If it's between 13-17, it's afternoon. Otherwise, its morning. See the link to the test in my question for a demonstration. It will work ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
public function greeting_msg() {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
   $hour = date('H');
   if ($hour >= 04 && $hour < 11) {
        $greeting = "Goedenmorgen";
   } elseif ($hour == 11) {
        $greeting = "Goedemiddag";
   } elseif ($hour >= 11 && $hour <= 17) {
        $greeting = "Goedemiddag";
   } elseif ($hour >= 17 && $hour <= 23) {
        $greeting = "Goedenavond";
   } else {
        $greeting = "Goedennacht";
    }
  return $greeting;
}
```

Comment: This is no different to a previous answer.

Comment: Not quite correct, added time zone and some refinements. But I understand your statement 

Comment: As it is, your answer may get flagged for deletion.  If you think it is different than other answers, then you should explain how it is different and why the difference is required.